# Why does the for loop only iterate once through the 2D array?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm new to coding and want to know why the for loop only works when `userInput` is "1". When `userInput` is "3", for example, the for loop does not continue to iterate, and just exits the for loop.

```
string[,] array =
{
   {"1", "2", "3"},
   {"4", "5", "6"},
   {"7", "8", "9"}
};

Console.Write("Enter a number from 1-9");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

//checks if userInput is a number in the array
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++, j++)
{
    if (array[i, j] == userInput)
    {
        array[i, j] = "X";
        Console.WriteLine("Index {0} has been changed to X", array[i, j]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because by incrementing `i` and `j` within the same loop you're effectively only reading diagonal elements. Consider using nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are going diagonally through it (i++ and j++ at the same time, so you will allways get 0/0 , 1/1, 2,2, ... n/n).

Try something like this instead:

```
    string[,] array =
    {
        {"1", "2", "3"},
        {"4", "5", "6"},
        {"7", "8", "9"}
    };

    Console.WriteLine("X / Y");

    for (int ix = 0; ix < array.GetLength(0); ix++)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < array.GetLength(0); iy++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ix + " / " + iy);
        }
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```